# MessageBrokerServlet with XmlWebAppInitializer approach

Tags: java, spring-boot, web.xml, servlet-3.0

I want to remove my web.xml file from my Spring boot project.

I'm trying an hybrid approach (as this [guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-xml-vs-java-config)).

I've this `MessageBrokerServlet` define in my `web.xml` as follow:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MessageBrokerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>flex.messaging.MessageBrokerServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MessageBrokerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/messagebroker/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This servlet uses a services-config.xml file about its configuration.

In the guide when I've mapped a servlet with a config location file I must write as follow:

```
ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container
      .addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));
```

So I link the servlet with its context file, but my MessageBrokerServlet has not a construction with parameter, so I've written this following code:

```
    // MessageBrokerServlet
    XmlWebApplicationContext context = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
    context.setConfigLocation("/WEB-INF/flex/services-config.xml");

    MessageBrokerServlet mbs = new MessageBrokerServlet();

    mbs.init(context.getServletConfig());
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic messageBrokenServlet = container.addServlet("MessageBrokerServlet", mbs);

    messageBrokenServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    messageBrokenServlet.addMapping("/messagebroker/*");

    container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
```

But when I get the `servletConfig` from context object it is null.

How can I pass to my `MessageBrokerServlet` the correct `servletConfig`, so I can linked to `services-config.xml file`?

Comment: `ServletContext` isn't an `ApplicationContext`. Instead you should use the passed in `ServletContext` (which should be an argument in your `WebApplicationInitializer` to obtain the config. Also if you are using Spring Boot you are trying very hard to work around it.

Comment: Yes, my scenario is with Spring boot

Comment: Why are you even trying to shoehorn Spring classes into working with `MessageBrokerServlet` which has nothing to do with Spring? The only ting you need to construct is the `MessageBrokerServlet` and wrap it in a `ServletRegistationBean` to pass the init parameter. Everything else you don't need. You are overthinking things and mixing `DispatcherServlet` (which is a totally different beast) with `MessageBrokerServlet`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lifecycle of the `MessageBrokerServlet` is handled by the servlet container. This is no difference (well a little maybe) in a Spring Boot application. So no need to call the `init` method.

The `MessageBrokerServlet` has also nothing to do with Spring so trying to load the configuration with Spring and then expect the `MessageBrokerServlet` to act on it won't do anything either.

With Spring Boot you can simply register a servlet as a bean in the application context and Spring Boot will take care of the registration. To register the servlet wrap it in a `ServletRegistrationBean` to pass the init parameters and further configuration. See also [this section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-embedded-container-servlets-filters-listeners-beans) of the Spring Boot Reference guide.

```
@Bean
public MessageBrokerServlet messageBrokerServlet() {
    return new MessageBrokerServlet();
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean<MessageBrokerServlet> messageBrokerServletRegistration() {
    ServletRegistrationBean<MessageBrokerServlet> registration = 
        new ServletRegistrationBean(messageBrokerServlet(), "/messagebroker/*");        
    return registration;
}
```

Place this in your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class or a specific `@Configuration` annotated class.

This mimics exactly what you have posted as the part in your `web.xml`. If you have additional `init-param` blocks (you didn't show them) you can use the `addInitParameter` method to add those to the `ServletRegistrationBean`.

Comment: Thank you very much